# Set drop down value in knockout

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

- I have a table(two column) to which we can add and remove rows.
- First    column is a dropdown and Second is a textarea.

I want to be able to push a new row into the table with **values**.

I tried the below code but only was able to push the comments text but not the selected option how do I get the dropdown to be selected as the value provided(from 'result').

**JS:(VM)**

```
    function RowData1(IDS, Comments) {
        var self = this;

        self.Comments = ko.observable(Comments).extend({ required: true });
        self.IDS = [{ value: "0", ids: "Choose..." }, { value: "1", ids: "Drip" }, { value: "2", ids: "Flood - Ditch" }, { value: "3", ids: "Flood - Gated Pipe" }, { value: "4", ids: "Pivot" }, { value: "5", ids: "Sprinkler" }, { value: "6", ids: "Other" }];
    }

//definition for Sec1
self.Sec1 = ko.observableArray([new RowData1()]);

//some function which will add the new row with values
function addData(){
    self.Sec1.push(RowData1(result.IDS, result.Comment));}//result has the IDS value and comment from an ajax call
```

**HTML:**

```
<table id="1Table" class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width: 22px;"><button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" type="button" data-bind=" click: $root.Sec1_AddRow">Add</button></th>
                        <th style=" text-align:center"><b>Irrigation Delivery System</b></th>
                        <th style=" text-align:center"><b>Comments</b></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody data-bind="foreach:Sec1">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <button class="btn btn-xs btn btn-danger" type="button" data-bind="click: $root.Sec1_RemoveRow">Remove</button>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select class="form-control" data-bind="options: IDS, value: IDS ,optionsValue:'value', optionsText:'ids'"></select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <textarea class="form-control" maxlength="500" style="width:50%" data-bind="value: Comments"></textarea>
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: Please provide the whole source code.

Comment: was wondering that might just add diversion from the point,any specific reason you ask that?

Comment: Guessing IDS should also be an observable to have the UI updated properly. Can you try making IDS an observable and assign it values appropriately (as we do for an observable)?

Comment: tried doing self.IDS = ko.observable([{ value: "0", ids: "Choose.......  its not working

Comment: It could be self.IDS = ko.observableArray([ ....
Try checking it using ko.observableArray as in section "Observable Array" of blog http://codinglookseasy.blogspot.in/2014/07/knockoutjs.html

Comment: Tried that as well it is having trouble binding the dropdown once I do that.

Comment: it is just similar to what I did except mine is in a function "RowData1"

Comment: check out the answer by @Nathan Fisher. Check if that works or will discuss again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need something like this

**ViewModel**

```
   function RowData(ids, comments) {
       var self = this;

       self.comments = ko.observable(comments).extend({
           required: true
       });
       self.ids = ko.observable(ids);
   }

   var Vm = function () {
       var self = this;
       //definition for Sec1
       self.Sec1 = ko.observableArray([]);
       self.selectedIDS = ko.observable();
       self.comment = ko.observable();

       //some function which will add the new row with values
       self.addRow = function () {
           self.Sec1.push(new RowData(self.selectedIDS(), self.comment()));
       }; //result has the IDS value and comment from an ajax call
       self.removeRow = function (item) {
           self.Sec1.remove(item);
       };

       self.IDS = ko.observableArray([{
           value: "0",
           ids: "Choose..."
       }, {
           value: "1",
           ids: "Drip"
       }, {
           value: "2",
           ids: "Flood - Ditch"
       }, {
           value: "3",
           ids: "Flood - Gated Pipe"
       }, {
           value: "4",
           ids: "Pivot"
       }, {
           value: "5",
           ids: "Sprinkler"
       }, {
           value: "6",
           ids: "Other"
       }]);

   };
   ko.applyBindings(new Vm());
```

**View**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ids" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Irrigation Delivery System</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <select id="ids" class="form-control" data-bind="options: IDS, value: selectedIDS, optionsText:'ids'"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="comment" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Comment</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <textarea class="form-control" maxlength="500" data-bind="value: comment"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: addRow">Add</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<table id="1Table" class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 22px;"></th>
            <th style=" text-align:center">
                <b>Irrigation Delivery System</b>

            </th>
            <th style=" text-align:center">
                <b>Comments</b>

            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach:Sec1">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-xs btn btn-danger" type="button" data-bind="click: $parent.removeRow">Remove</button>
            </td>
            <td data-bind="text: ids().ids">

            </td>
            <td ><p data-bind="text: comments"></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gonefishern/vh76xcjv/)**

Comment: Thanks @nathan I was not thinking of changing the UI work flow but thsi works.